# Angular-Strap Modal Does Not Load Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

For some reason the modal box works just fine but it does not load any templates I specify.

My Controller has this code;

```
var brnSearchModal = $modal({ scope: $scope, template: "app/rrn/searchBrn.html", contentTemplate: false, html: true, show: false });

$scope.showModal = function () {
    brnSearchModal.$promise.then(brnSearchModal.show);
};
```

My HTML looks like this;

```
<button data-ng-click="showModal()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top">
    BRN Lookup
</button>
```

And my template is in a file and looks like this;

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" ng-show="title">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind="title">Hello, World!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="content">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is no error everything seems to be working fine but the template does not load. If I debug angular-strap at one point the template is loaded but then disappears in and leaves a blank modal.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ng-show="title"`, `ng-bind="title"` from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the bs-modal attribute: see [examples](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##modals-examples)

```
<button data-ng-click="showModal()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" bs-modal="brnSearchModal">
    BRN Lookup
</button>
```

Otherwise use the data-template attribute directly without using the JS to show the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-animation="am-fade-and-slide-top" data-template="app/rrn/searchBrn.html" bs-modal="modal">
    BRN Lookup
</button>
```

I think when you put `bs-modal="modal"` modal is somehow pre-defined in the angular-strap library.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove `ng-show="title`" , `ng-show="content"` or `ng-bind="title"` from the template. You should make sure that the template has no `ng-show`.

Comment: if you want to show the modal title, pls remove the ng-bind-html="title"

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but in case others are looking for a solution to the same problem.  I found I had to explicitly set templateUrl to falsy when setting template to an html string